# Hide via jquery all instances of a specific line of html

Tags: jquery, hide, parent

I want to hide, via jquery, all instances of only this exact string:
`<p>description</p>`

I must be missing something obvious:

http://jsfiddle.net/deekster/pSJ95/

Thanks.

```
<p>name</p>
<p>description</p>
<p>address</p>
```

`$('p contains(description)').parent().remove();`

Comment: For future reference, you should post your code in the question as well as a link to your JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to hide, via jquery, all instances of only this exact string: `<p>description</p>`

Eventhough you have issue with the selector, contains will not do an exact match, it will do a wildcard match to match all element containing the string `description` as its content. To do an exact macth you can do a filter.

```
$('p').filter(function () {
    return this.innerHTML === "description";
}).remove(); //if you want to just hide them use .hide(), .remove() will remove it from DOM.
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T2vQH/)**

Comment: Beautiful. Works great and good to learn the right way how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Missing the `:` on your `contains` selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/RqDpg/

`$('p:contains(description)').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p:contains(description)').remove();
```

You also need to remove `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is missing the `:`. Try:

```
$('p:contains("description")').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide description text with below code:

```
$('p:contains(description)').hide();
```

Check [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/5GVCD/1/)